# Pandas Period/DateTimeIndex --> Days in Year (including leap years)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to perform some interest rate calculations across various conventions, one of which is actual/actual representing the actual days in period divided by the actual days in year.

In most cases, this would be actual/365, however I'm trying to account for leap years and can't seem to find an elegant way to do it without writing a bunch of loops.

```
periods = pd.PeriodIndex(start='05-2019', freq='M', periods=60)
# how to make series of same length consisting of # of days in each year?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
periods.shift(12).to_timestamp() - periods.to_timestamp()
```

It gives:

```
TimedeltaIndex(['366 days', '366 days', '366 days', '366 days', '366 days',
                '366 days', '366 days', '366 days', '366 days', '366 days',
                '365 days', '365 days', '365 days', '365 days', '365 days',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[366 if p.is_leap_year else 365 for p in periods]
```